# How can I predict bigger sized image if the model is trained on a smaller sized image using keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm using the following keras code with tensorflow backend to classify the difference between dog and a cat. It is not predicting any image above 800x800 image. How can I predict or resize the image to predict an hd image.

**Code to train:**

```
# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.models import model_from_json
from scipy.misc import imresize


# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(
    training_set,
    samples_per_epoch=80,
    nb_epoch=100,
    validation_data=test_set,
    nb_val_samples=2000
)


print(training_set.class_indices)
```

**Code to predict:**

```
from keras.models import model_from_json

json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(model_json)
# load weights into new model
model.load_weights("model.h5")

# evaluate loaded model on test data
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


import shutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests

url = raw_input("Please enter the image url/link")
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('test.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)


from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np

test = image.load_img('test.jpg')
test = image.img_to_array(test)
test = np.expand_dims(test, axis=0)
result = model.predict(test)

if result[0][0] == 1:
    prediction = 'dog'
    print prediction
else:
    prediction = 'cat'
    print prediction
```

Comment: If you are using TensorFlow backend, probably the the best option would be to write a [custom layer](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) that calls [`tf.image.resize_images`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images). Otherwise you can resize the data before inputting it to the model, for example with SciPy's [`imresize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html).

Comment: I don't mind training the model again with input as none, but is there any way to predict without re-training?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Keras docs you can just specify the target size using:

```
test = image.load_img('test.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))
```

see https://keras.io/applications/ for an example.

Comment: That's right, looking at [the source](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py) (since the function doesn't seem to be anywhere in the documentation) it does perform the resize and, what is more, the function returns a [PIL `Image` object](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html), so in principle you can perform yourself any operation supported by PIL on it before calling `img_to_array`.

Comment: I get this error : 
ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_7_input to have shape (None, 64, 64, 3) but got array with shape (1, 224, 224, 3)

Comment: just change target size to 64,64

Comment: @convolutionBoy Yes. It was 64,64 all the time but it's unable to predict a bigger sized image

Comment: sorry i meant you need to downsize the bigger image to 64,64. that is the only way around it.